# Is there a way to subscribe to different topics at the same time in rospy?

Tags: ros, rospy, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am subscribing to various topics and I wish to print them into a .csv log file, but I am not able to print any one of them outside their own callback function.

You can see the code at [Click for Code](https://gist.github.com/argahsuknesib/e945a48472e3fb320c35f902e8238266) and it will be great if you could let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382615/is-there-a-way-to-subscribe-to-different-topics-at-the-same-time-in-rospy?/) by [argahsuknesib](https://answers.ros.org/users/72946/argahsuknesib/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-16**:
Isn't this something you'd want to do with `rosbag`? Especially because you want to convert the data to `.csv`?

**Comment by [argahsuknesib](https://answers.ros.org/users/72946/argahsuknesib/) on 2021-07-16**:
Yes, I am trying to do that. But I was not successful in doing the conversion to csv, will you please tell me a working rosabg_to_csv convertor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could just create the subscriber inside a class and use a member variable to save them in the correct order or use the time as a key and then create a table when you desire.

Or if the data is synchronized you could try to take a look at http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters.

In any case, take a look at the message filters package.

---

Originally posted by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) with karma: 378 on 2021-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [argahsuknesib](https://answers.ros.org/users/72946/argahsuknesib/) on 2021-07-15**:
Thank you so much, I will look into it. Have a good day